# Can not import pip modules

Tags: python, import, python-3.7

While coding on python I faced a problem with importing modules using PIP. The thing is that I can not import a single module, for example "camelcase". Would someone help me?

```py
import camelcase

c = camelcase.CamelCase()
txt = "hello world"
print(c.hump(txt))
```

It is expected that the output will be "Hello World". But there is following an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "mycode.py", line 1, in 
>   import camelcase
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'

Comment: Did you actually install this? How?

Comment: you need to install the package https://pypi.org/project/camelcase/ via `pip install camelcase`

Answer (score 1):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'.Error clearly said that you need to install camelcase package

[official docs of camelcase package](https://pypi.org/project/camelcase/)

[virtual env set up](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/)

Use the following command:

pip install camelcase

```
import camelcase  
c = camelcase.CamelCase()   
txt = "hello world"   
print(c.hump(txt))
```

Instead of third party package you can also do

```
print(txt.title())
```